# Manage Commerce Server 09 Users in SharePoint Groups

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-commerce-server

I'm pretty new to Commerce Server 09 and its integration into SharePoint.  I have a requirement to use SharePoint groups to manage the CS users.  I've got the VPC demo loaded and read about the pipelines, etc., but I'm not quite sure where to start.

Has anybody done this or have any ideas?  Anything that help get me going in the right direction would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Corey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like when I register a user under with the CS Extension webparts, they are created in the CS profile system as well as SP.  The default membership provider is the UPMProvider.  I can see the users in SP and their username is prefixed with UPMProvider:, very interesting.

I can extend/copy/bastardize the CS webparts and add users to the necessary SP groups myself.